# similar to accordion issue but not using accordion

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I have 4 div sections.

```
<div id= section1> Edit Button

 
continue button<br/>
</div <br/>

<div id= section2> Edit Button 
<br/> 
continue button<br/>
</div<br/>

<div id= section3> Edit Button 
<br/> 
continue button<br/>
</div<br/>

<div id= section4> Edit Button 
<br/> 
continue button<br/>
</div<br/>
```

in this scenario when a continue button for a respective section is clicked I will go to the next section where user has to enter inputs in text boxes.
on clicking continue I hide the controls and show a div with all inputs entered by user are written into it.

on clicking edit will show controls section of respective section and hides all other controls sections and edit buttons making user to enter only one section details but nt other sections.

so this happens with each and every section.

my problem is: sections are dynamic.. I can show or hide sections so in that case how do I maintain the continue and edit button functionality?

I need suggestions to achieve this functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Assign a class for edit button and continue button first.

Then write an event handler for the button, hide all first and then make visible the button which was clicked.

Pseudo code:

```
// hide all button defined by their class name
$(".editButtonClass, .continueButtonClass").hide();

// --> if clicked button is a edit button do your job
if( $(this).hasClass("editButton")) {
    // do your job

    // --> the button which was clicked should be visible
    $(this).show();
}
```

This is a generic approach so it should work for dynamic elements.